# В случае ошибки (неправоты) пользователя (признанной им) как деликатно заметить ему о том, что оценку надо забрать или подкорректировать?

Tags: android, google-play

Увы, такое периодически встречается. )

А плохие оценки, сами понимаете, сильно снижают среднюю оценку, репутацию, нажитую непосильным трудом. )

Comment: Если он признал, почему бы прямо не попросить исправить оценку?

Comment: Либо напишите второй Android System WebView)

Comment: Истинный поэт пишет для себя, а не для плебса :)

Answer (score 6):

**Пользователь всегда прав**

Вы разрабатываете приложение для пользователя. У вас есть аудитория, на которую это приложение рассчитано. Если эта аудитория (либо ее часть) считает, что в приложении есть какой-то косяк, и они говорят ***"фуууу, вы не можете это пофиксить, два балла вам"*** или что-то подобное, то, скорее всего, так и есть. По крайней мере **так это видит пользователь**.

Это ваша проблема, так как вы должны в своем приложении объяснить пользователю, что это фича, а не баг, и прочее (пользователь должен пользоваться, у него не должно возникать вопросов `почему то или это не работает?` / `почему это работает не так, как мне объяснили?` / `почему это работает не так, как я понял?`). Но я, конечно, не знаю, что за неправоту там признают ваши пользователи.

К примеру, если у вас определенные пользователи говорят ***"приложение говно"*** (может, они любят **большую грудь**, а у вашего приложения она **маленькая**), то стоит либо переработать его так, чтобы оно нравилось этим пользователям (сделать грудь **адаптивной/всегда большой**), либо так, чтобы они не только его не скачивали, но даже не натыкались бы на него (описать приложение как "приложение с **МАЛЕНЬКОЙ**" грудью).

Но это лично мое мнение, которое, к тому же, касается лишь множественных случаев. Если у вас такое возникает с конкретными индивидуумами (пару случаев), то тогда вам нужно уже искать индивидуальный подход.

И вообще, это тогда вопрос по психологии, а не на Стак.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы написал нечто, вроде:
"Вот видите... А Вы мне "минус" в репу ни за что влепили :)"

Если после этого человек не уберет "минус" - тут 3 варианта:

1. Возможно, человек не прочитал ваш ответ.
2. Возможно, он настолько глуп, что просто не понял даже настолько толстый намек. (в этом случае "деликатный подход" тут точно не сработает).
3. Возможно, человек считает, что на момент выставления "минуса" он всё сделал правильно и поступал по обстоятельствам, актуальным на тот момент. При этом, конечный результат беседы не имеет к этому никакого отношения. То было тогда, а это - сейчас. Совершенно разные вещи. (Да, бывают и такие люди...)